# adding scroll in properties Qlikview

Tags: scroll, qlikview

So, has any one had a problem with the scroll properties.

I in the qvpp file i set `overflow:scroll` but the scroll bar does not appear.

Here is the picture that shows how it is  but not how it should be:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zPEG3UR.png?1]

Comment: Could you please show all of your code (the code containing the overflow:scroll part)